# Spring MVC 3 with Hibernate - Whats my model for use in ModelAndView?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-3

I've just setup my first Spring MVC 3 project with Hibernate 3 using Maven.

Now I'm used to having a controller-page with my controller and a model package with my models,
but with hibernate integrated what i now have is:

```
.
|____main
| |____java
| | |____com
| | | |____cqrify
| | | | |____tellus
| | | | | |____App.java
| | | | | |____controller
| | | | | | |____ContactController.java
| | | | | |____dao
| | | | | | |____ContactDAO.java
| | | | | | |____impl
| | | | | | | |____ContactDAOImpl.java
| | | | | |____form
| | | | | | |____Contact.java
| | | | | |____service
| | | | | | |____ContactService.java
| | | | | | |____impl
| | | | | | | |____ContactServiceImpl.java
| |____resources
| | |____config.properties
| | |____log4j.xml
| | |____Messages.properties
| | |____META-INF
| |____webapp
| | |____resources
| | | |____css
| | | |____gfx
| | | |____js
| | |____WEB-INF
| | | |____classes
| | | |____spring
| | | | |____appServlet
| | | | | |____servlet-context.xml
| | | | |____root-context.xml
| | | |____views
| | | | |____editContact.jsp
| | | | |____newContact.jsp
| | | | |____showContacts.jsp
| | | | |____includes
| | | |   |____taglib_includes.jsp
| | | |____web.xml
|____test
| |____java
| |____resources
| | |____log4j.xml
|____test.txt
```

What I understand is that I'm to autowire "ContactService" as that is now my "model", but how do I use with with ModelAndView?

My controller

```
import com.cqrify.tellus.form.Contact;
import com.cqrify.tellus.service.ContactService;

@Controller
public class ContactController {
    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView listContacts(){
        Map<String, Object> contactMap;

        contactMap.put("contactList", contactService.listContacts());

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("showContacts", "ContactService", contactMap);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

As seen above

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("showContacts", "ContactService", contactMap);
```

is this right that "ContactService" will now be my modelName or have i completely missed something?

Comment: "Right"? You can name it whatever you want. IMO it's a poor name, since it's not a `ContactService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can simply return:

```
new ModelAndView("showContacts", "contactList", contactService.listContacts());
```

This means that you want to render `showContacts` view and the list of contacts will be available for the view under `contactList` name.

`ContactService` is a business object used to find (fetch) the model, IMHO it should not be used to name the model itself.